# How To Do Error Handling with React Select

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I started to play around with react select and I what I cannot seem to find in their documentation is to how to do error states. Does react select have a built in way to tell it that its in error states and make the border red?

Comment: you could update the state with the selected value, and based on criteria add a certain class that shows red border. this can be achieved without react-select also

Comment: Yeah I am starting to think that is what you have to do

Answer (score 2):

CSS class

```
.react-select-error div {
  border-color: #e74c3c; 
}

.react-select-error:hover div {
  border-color: #e74c3c; 
}
```

HTML code

```
<Select
       options={yourList}
       value={yourSelectedValue}
       onChange={e => { /* your code */ }} 
       menuPortalTarget={document.body}
       styles={{ menuPortal: base => ({ ...base, zIndex: 9999 }) }}
       className={ 1 == 1 ? 'react-select-error' : ''}
/>
```

The "1 == 1" have to be your condition to show the red color, if you are using formik then you can use formik.errors.field_name instead of "1 == 1", or whatever you have as condition.

I had a certain problem to remove the blue color from the :focus-visible of the browser, If someone could complement the answer I would greatly appreciate it :)

Answer (score 0):

Add class based on selected value stored in state.

Live demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-select-error-handling-60093